# $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{1 + x^n}$ does not converge uniformly, yet we can change the order of integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am trying to show that $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{1 + x^n}$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1]$, yet we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)dx = \int_0^1 \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\right)dx$$

For the first part, I showed that when $x\in[0,1)$, we have $\lim f_n (x)=0$. When $x=1$, we have $\lim f_n(x)=\frac{1}{2}$. This implies that $f_n$ cannot converge uniformly, since if it does, the limit function has to be continuous, which is not the case here.

But I'm not sure about the integral parts. For the integral on the right hand side, apparently it is zero. But I tried to computed the left hand side integral, I got stuck:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 1 - \frac{1}{1+x^n}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^n}dx\right)$$

Comment: do you know the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @user251257 Uh, no, but perhaps I should learn that

Comment: it depends. Are you learning the riemann integral right now, or lebesgue integral? DCT is a theorem in lebesgue integration theory.

Comment: @user251257 This is a practice problem from GRE, so I would assume Riemann integral.

Comment: without measure theory: $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[0,\epsilon]; 0<\epsilon <1$. Split the integral up and deal with the two pieces separately.

Comment: Hint: $0 \le f_n(x) = \frac 1 n x \cdot \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x^n} \le \frac1n \cdot \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x^n}$ on $[0,1]$ and logarithm.

Comment: A comment on applying theorems: even if the hypothesis of a theorem is not satisfied, the conclusion can still be true. It doesn't *folllow*, but it can still be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $ 0 \leq f_n(x) \leq x^n$ on [$[0,1]$ which implies  $0 \leq \int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)dx \leq \dfrac{1}{n+1}$ and so $\int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)dx \to 0 = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx. $